What's the difference between using `useEffect` with an empty dependency array and a conditional?
Based on the article outlined in the React docs: You Might Not Need An Effect, they explain that logic which should only be executed once should be wrapped in an init clause.
i.e.
// Will run init flow only once per application lifecycle

let didInit = false;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didInit) {
      didInit = true;

      loadDataFromLocalStorage();
      checkAuthToken();
    }
  }, []);
}

Or:
// Will run init flow whenever component is mounted

function App() {
  const didInit = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didInit.current) {
      didInit.current = true;

      loadDataFromLocalStorage();
      checkAuthToken();
    }
  }, []);
}

However, if moved outside the effect, the behavior remains the same. So if the behavior's the same, why would you need the hook?

In other cases, it may not keep the same. For example, using this with useState.

The dependency array in the useEffect() hook tells when the hook to run. If its an empty array, the useEffect hook will run only when the component loads, but say you have some state variable in the dependency array, if that variable changes then the useEffect hook will be triggered again and will update the information within the useEffect hook.

It is not about whether or no the logic runs. It is about when the logic runs and what it does.
Putting things outside means the callback runs during rendering. And inside effect means it runs after the render.
There is also the difference of intent. React component's function body job is to return the UI representation. Side effects should ideally go inside useEffect callbacks. React team has been recommending this since beginning and it is becoming more important now with concurrent React, where rendering can be paused midway and started again. Then your sideEffecty code will run again and again.
The same doc you refer to links to these:

https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure
https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects


Using useEffect is the recommended approach for several reasons:

Clearly distinguishes side effects from the rest of the component logic (Encapsulation).
Ensures function run/re-run at the appropriate time in the component lifecycle (Lifecycle Alignment).
Prevents issues with server-side rendering (SSR Safety).
Provides a built-in mechanism for cleaning up side effects(Cleanup Management).

By following these practices, you can ensure your code is robust, predictable, and maintainable within the React ecosystem.

Two of those points don't apply to the example in the question

Let's compare the behaviors:
Initialization Logic Inside useEffect
1. Global Initialization (Persistent across App Lifecycle):
let didInit = false;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didInit) {
      didInit = true;

      loadDataFromLocalStorage();
      checkAuthToken();
    }
  }, []);
}

didInit is declared as a global flag to ensure that the initialization runs only once per application lifecycle. This means it will not run again, even if the component unmounts and remounts.
2. Component-specific Initialization (Runs on Each Mount):
function App() {
  const didInit = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didInit.current) {
      didInit.current = true;
      loadDataFromLocalStorage();
      checkAuthToken();
    }
  }, []); 
}

useRef makes the component's lifetime persistent without triggering re-renders. We combine useRef with useEffect to mimic component mount and unmount behaviors.
This means the initialization logic runs once on mount and reruns on remount.
Initialization Logic Outside useEffect
1. Global Initialization Without useEffect:
let didInit = false;

if (!didInit) {
  didInit = true;
  loadDataFromLocalStorage();
  checkAuthToken();
}

Here is what you should avoid and what I was pointing out in my original answer -> **Moving the logic outside useEffect will result in a different behavior, leading to potential issues and bugs.
You should always use useEffect for side effects to maintain predictable and stable component behavior.
2. Component-specific Initialization Without useEffect:
function App() {
  const didInit = useRef(false);

  if (!didInit.current) {
    didInit.current = true;
    loadDataFromLocalStorage();
    checkAuthToken();
  }
}

The best for the end! Running initialization logic directly in the render method is a disaster in the making.
This will undoubtedly cause rendering issues and goes against React's best practices, as side effects should not run during render.

Different how? That's what the OP is asking.

True! I was responding to the OP's statement, 'However, if moved outside the effect, the behavior remains the same.' I was pointing out that the behavior actually changes when the element is moved outside of the effect's scope.

Does it though? How does the behaviour change?

I've updated my response. Please let me know if anything remains unclear.
